# How to preserve formatting when using capture.output in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I used capture.output to capture the printed output. However, the result displayed using renderPrint is very messy (see Image 1 attached). Is there a way to display it while preserving its original formatting (Image 2 attached)?

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here are some lines of my codes:

**in server.R**

```
nway_result      <- reactiveValues() 

nway_result$df <- capture.output(Nway(var_dd$selected, mynode$selected), file= NULL)

    output$nway <- renderPrint({
        if (input$dd_options == 6) { 
            nway_result$df
        }
    })
```

**in ui.R**

```
verbatimTextOutput('nway')
```

image 1:

[image: Displayed output (messy)]

image 2:

[image: Desired output (neat)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code I'm currently using for one of my projects. It displays the output of a `lm` call together with an echoed version of the call.

```
library(shiny)
library(evaluate)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(verbatimTextOutput("text")),
  function(input, output)
    output$text <- renderText(
      paste(
        capture.output(replay(
          evaluate(function()
            lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
          )
        )),
        collapse = "\n")
    )
)
```

[image]

Since you don't need the call to be echoed, this simplified version should do what you want.

```
# context: server.R
output$nway <- renderText({
    if (input$dd_options == 6) { 
        paste(nway_result$df, collapse = "\n")
    }
})

# context: ui.R
verbatimTextOutput("nway")
```

Comment: It works, @Gregor. Thanks so much! One thing I didn't expect: it only works if I use verbatimTextOutput with renderText (not renderPrint). Any idea why? I thought verbatimTextOutput should always be used with renderPrint.

Comment: As far as i can tell, `\n` is handeled differently by `textOutput` and `verbatimTextOutput`. Other than that, both functions are very similar in the sense that they display a string. I don't really know a lot about the difference between the two `render` functions though. So should i replace `renderPrint` with `renderText` in my answer?

Comment: Yes, we should replace renderPrint with renderText, Thanks!